# Comparing two Resizable Array Sets

Tags: java

I am trying to find the union and intersection of two ResizableArraySet objects I made using a modified Set Interface that has a few methods taken away. I am having a tough time passing both sets and processing them both. I know that's not what exactly happens, but here is some code to better explain what I am trying to do. Here is the call in my tester.

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString((set.union(set2)).toArray()));
```

So set is an object I made in the tester, and set2 is another ResizableArraySet object that I made to compare to set. When I print that, I just get an array of set2.

Here are the constructors and instance variables.

```
public class ResizableArraySet<T> implements Set<T> {

private int numberOfEntries;
private int size;
T[] array;

/**
 * Constructor for Set without size variable (Default size is 10)
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
public ResizableArraySet() {
    array = (T[]) new Object[10];
}

/**
 * Constructor for the Set with size variable
 * 
 * @param size
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked" })
public ResizableArraySet(int size) {
    this.size = size;
    array = (T[]) new Object[size];
}
```

Here is relevant code for my union method. If the intersection method is necessary, I can provide that in an edit, but I think the problem is the same in both methods.

```
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
@Override
public Set<T> union(Set<T> anotherSet) {
    T[] newArray = (T[]) new Object[anotherSet.getSize()];
    int entries = this.size;
    System.out.println(entries); //Get 0, when the size is not 0
    for (int x = 0; x < entries; x++) {
        if (anotherSet.contains(array[x]) == false) {
            anotherSet.add(array[x]);
        }
    }
    return anotherSet;
}
```

Here are my add, remove, and contains methods

```
    @Override
public boolean add(T newEntry) {
    if (contains(newEntry)) {
        return false;
    } else if (array.length > numberOfEntries) {
        array[numberOfEntries] = newEntry;
        numberOfEntries++;
        return true;
    } else {
        array = Arrays.copyOf(array, (array.length * 2));
        array[numberOfEntries] = newEntry;
        numberOfEntries++;
        return true;
    }
}

@Override
public boolean remove(T anEntry) {
    if (contains(anEntry) != true) {
        return false;
    }
    for (int x = 0; x < numberOfEntries; x++) {
        if (array[x].equals(anEntry)) {
            // Loop to move the values down one index in the main array
            for (int a = x; a < numberOfEntries; a++) {
                array[a] = array[a + 1];
            }
            numberOfEntries--;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean contains(T anEntry) {
    for (int x = 0; x < numberOfEntries; x++) {
        if (array[x].equals(anEntry)) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

So to sum up my problem. I'm having trouble comparing both objects, because they both have to use the same methods [contains(anEntry), add(anEntry), getSize()]

Let me know if I'm missing any helpful code.
Does anyone have a solution to my problem

Comment: Where is `numberOfEntries` set? Why can't you call `this.size()` instead of using `numberOfEntries`?

Comment: If `numberOfEntries` is the incorrect value, then your code that adds entries to the set and removes entries from the set is probably not updating it correctly.

Comment: @DarshanMehta numberOfEntries is an instance variable outside of the constructor. When I call this.size and this.getSize(), I still get the same error, entries is still 0. I will edit the post with this code

Comment: `because they both have to use the same methods`.  Of course they do, but they are acting on different data, because each object should have its own instance variables, so the fact that they are using the same methods should not make any difference, unless you've defined static variables that you're sharing between different object instances.

Comment: You should post the code of any methods that add to the set or remove from the set, i.e., methods that should update the value of `numberOfEntries`.

Comment: Also show how you declare the instance variable `numberOfEntries`.

Comment: In the future, read up on posting a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

Comment: You should explicitly set `numberOfEntries` to 0 in both your constructors.

Comment: Also, you don't set `size` to 10 in your default constructor.

Comment: @DavidChoweller I have to set default size to 10 in the empty constructor for my assignment.

Comment: But you're not doing that.  You're just declaring the array with size 10, but you're not setting the `size` instance variable to match the size of your array.

Comment: Ideally, every constructor should set every instance variable if possible, unless one constructor is calling another constructor.

Comment: @DavidChoweller damn, you're right.

Comment: @DavidChoweller Also, the problem is apparent when I try and print the array for the original set object.

Comment: Also post the code of your `contains` method.

Comment: You're also not modifying the `size` instance variable when you resize the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how your union should look like.  It uses an iterator, which you'll need to implement.  This is because your `otherSet` variable is of type `Set<T>`, not `ResizableArraySet<T>`, so you don't have access to its array directly.

```
public Set<T> union(Set<T> anotherSet) {
    ResizableArraySet<T> newSet = new ResizableArraySet<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfEntries; i++) {
        newSet.add(array[i]);
    }
    Iterator<T> it = anotherSet.iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        T el = it.next();
        if (!newSet.contains(el)) {
            newSet.add(el);
        }
    }
    return newSet;
}
```